# Dynamically changing attributes for properties

Tags: .net, soap, attributes

I am accessing a web service which provides a single method `ProcessMessage` this method looks like:

```
<System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderAttribute("payloadManifest", Direction:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderDirection.InOut), _
     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://exampleurl/operations/ProcessMessage/v1_01/GetTest1" & _
        "", RequestNamespace:="http://exampleurl", ResponseNamespace:="http://exampleurl", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)> _
Public Sub ProcessMessage(ByRef payload As Payload)
    Try
        Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("ProcessMessage", New Object() {payload})
        payload = CType(results(0), Payload)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

This works fine, however, this method is to be used for various different functions. If the `SoapDocumentMethodAttribute` `Action` is changed `ProcessMessage` returns different values.

Example:

Change

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://exampleurl/operations/ProcessMessage/v1_01/GetTest1"
```

To

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://exampleurl/operations/ProcessMessage/v1_01/GetTest2"
```

Now the problem is, as far as I can see, this `Action` needs to be hard-coded into the file and therefore I can only run 1 method with each compiled program. Is there any way of dynamically changing the `Action` or should I be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a workaround, but it's not exactly ideal. Basically, we were setting this attribute to populate the `SOAPAction` header. But we decided to change the `SOAPAction` header directly rather than through the attributes. Much simpler but surely a hack-y method.